# Swift Attributed Title Syntax

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let introText = "This is sample "
let facebookText = "Text"
loginButton.setTitle("\(introText)\(facebookText)", forState: .Normal)
loginButton.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15.5)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, introText.characters.count))
loginButton.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Arial-Bold", size: 15.5)!, range: NSMakeRange(introText.characters.count, facebookText.characters.count))
loginButton.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, introText.characters.count + facebookText.characters.count))
```

in this form:

```
loginButton.setAttributedTitle(NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "\(introText)\(facebookText)",
    attributes: [
        // attributes go here
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.colorFromCode(0x151515),
    ]), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Is it possible for me to do this? I'm having trouble figuring out how to include the range on included attributes.

**EDIT**

Sorry if it wasn't obvious, but what my code does is it creates an attributed string that reads "This is sample **Text**" with the word `Text` bolded as shown. I'm trying to rewrite this code to be in the form of the second syntax I'm showing, if it's even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to do using attributed text?

Comment: what does it mean "trouble figuring out how to include the range on included attributes" ? what is the trouble ?

Comment: I'm not able to include the range in the second form. I've been playing around with the syntax but can't seem to be able to include it. I searched through documentation, but I couldn't see anything with including attributes like range in the second form, so I was unsure if you can do it @NazmulHasan

Comment: do you want set range in your button?

Comment: please mention your desired output.

Comment: yes, so part of the button text will be normal, and the other part will be bold. That's what is happening in the example I included @NazmulHasan

Comment: My desired output would be text that reads `This is sample Text`, and `This is sample ` would be unbold, and `Text` would be bold @UmairAfzal

Comment: what about titleColor check this https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton

Comment: @Thomas check my answer

Comment: okay @Thomas I have posted the answer according to your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an attributed text with bolded part, this will do it for you.

```
extension String {

  func getPartOfStringBold(boldPart:String)-> NSAttributedString{
    return getPartOfStringBold(boldPart, font: UIFont(name: "Taz-Bold", size: 13)!)
 }

//Make your string bold
  func getPartOfStringBold(boldPart:String, font:UIFont)-> NSAttributedString{
    let attributtedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName:font]
    let rangePart: NSRange = (attributtedString.string as NSString).rangeOfString(boldPart)
    attributtedString.addAttributes(attrs, range: rangePart)
    return attributtedString
  }

//Make your string Italic
  func getPartOfStringItalic(italicPart:String)-> NSAttributedString{
    let attributtedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)

    if let font = UIFont(name: "Taz-LightItalic", size: 13)
    {
        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
        let rangePart: NSRange = (attributtedString.string as NSString).rangeOfString(italicPart)
        attributtedString.addAttributes(attrs, range: rangePart)
    }
    return attributtedString
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I have understood your problem, you want to make a portion of test as bold if yes then here is an extension which I am using for this purpose

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension String
{

static func makeTextBold(preBoldText:String, boldText:String, postBoldText:String, fontSzie:CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {

    let boldAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: fontSzie) as? AnyObject]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:boldText, attributes:boldAttrs as? [String:AnyObject])

    let lightAttr = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: fontSzie) as? AnyObject]
    let finalAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:preBoldText, attributes:lightAttr as? [String:AnyObject])

    let postText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:postBoldText, attributes:lightAttr as? [String:AnyObject])

    finalAttributedText.appendAttributedString(attributedString)
    finalAttributedText.appendAttributedString(postText)
    // print(finalAttributedText)
    return finalAttributedText
}
}
```

So basically what this function is doing is that you pass three parameters for text and one for fot size and it will return an attributed string.

Here is an example usage for your case

```
myLabel.attributedText = String.makeTextBold("This is sample", boldText: "Text", postBoldText: "", fontSzie: 21)
```

the output would be

This is sample **Text**

I hope this answer the question :-)

Comment: this is what i have answered before you Umair. Didnt you see my answer? Please take a look at the answers before you answer them

Comment: @GaneshKumar I have posted what I have used and found usefull. Its the choice of OP that which answer he/she selects. cheers :-)

Comment: i agree that. but the answers should have different approaches right?

Comment: Yeah they do. You are using NSRange and I am not.

Comment: NSRange is big deal here ?

Comment: What is the issue ? You have your answer and I have mine.